# How to edit logs directory and save?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have this code and can successfully load loss information. I want to edit this information and save again so later I can load with tensorboard for display, how can I achieve that?

```
from tensorflow.python.summary import event_accumulator as ea

acc = ea.EventAccumulator("train")
acc.Reload()

# Print tags of contained entities, use these names to retrieve entities as below
print(acc.Tags())

xy_l2_loss = [(s.step, s.value) for s in acc.Scalars('seq2seq/loss/loss')]

print(xy_l2_loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to store it in a file:

```
import pickle
from tensorflow.python.summary import event_accumulator as ea

acc = ea.EventAccumulator("train")
acc.Reload()

# Print tags of contained entities, use these names to retrieve entities as below
print(acc.Tags())

xy_l2_loss = [(s.step, s.value) for s in acc.Scalars('seq2seq/loss/loss')]

print(xy_l2_loss)
xy_l2_loss = 'asdf'
#store data
with open('somefile.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(xy_l2_loss, f)
#load data
with open('somefile.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    xy_l2_loss = pickle.load(f)
```